# Javascript Error: 400 Bad Request and ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, php

I know this is a crappy questions and that I am a rookie, so sorry about that. I have googled both the 400 error and the reference error and I'm trying to figure out which one I need to focus on, because one may be causing the other? Or are they both totally unrelated errors?

The code that follows is a snippet from a page that I have created that takes a person's routing number, account number, and name (using php) and then uses Stripe JS api to create a bank account. The goal is to verify this account using micro transactions. As its setup right now, i dont understand why it does not post to the bankverify2.php page I have specified. Any ideas? Do i need to provide more code?
Thanks community.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if ( !empty($_POST["firstName"]) and !empty( $_POST["lastName"]) and !empty($_POST["routingNumber"])  and !empty( $_POST["accountNumber"]) )
    { 
    ?>
        <form id="stripe-form" action="bankverify2.php" method="post">
          <input id="stripe-token" type="hidden" name="token" />
        </form>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <script>
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_2LS3Dvu59TCBC5F2tPsehEry');
        stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        routing_number: '<?php echo $_POST["routingNumber"];?>',
        account_number: '<?php echo $_POST["accountNumber"];?>',
        account_holder_name: '<?php echo $_POST["firstName"] .' '.$_POST["lastName"];?>',
        account_holder_type: 'individual',
      }).then(function(result) {
        // Handle result.error or result.token
        // var token = blah.getToken(yada_yada);
        var tokenBank = result.token;
        $('#stripe-token').val(tokenBank);
        $('#stripe-form').submit();
      });    

        </script>

    <?php    
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Complete all of the fields.';
    }
}
```

Chrome Inspector Console Output after submitting form:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at bankverify.php:24
    at

[JS Chrome Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4tjD.png)

Comment: lol `bankverify.php:24` there you go, go check that, line 24 (what line is that?)

Comment: Did you include jquery?

Comment: Regulus getting straight to the point... (You probably don't have jquery), while you're on your page type `$` into the console, hit enter, and you should get... `ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}`

Answer (score 1):

They seem unrelated.

For the reference error it would seem that you are trying to use jQuery in your file `bankverify2.php` is the action for your form submission, which doesn't seem to be defined in that context.

As for the bad request you seem to be building your request incorrectly. Try adding a check for `result.error` in your promise callback, like I've done below:

http://jsbin.com/fibagopeho/edit?js,console

That way you'll get a clearer error message logged to the console to figure out what is going wrong. Alternatively you can check the request in your Network tab in the browser:

[debugging-in-js-callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdoXO.png)

As for the PHP-code you could try a function that checks if they all exist instead of having that long if-statement:

```php
$check_array = array('firstName', 'lastName', 'routingNumber');
    if (!array_diff($check_array, array_keys($_POST)))
        // all are present
```